# Generated Razor Files Don't Work After MVC4 Upgrade

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

After upgrading a working MVC 3 solution with Razor views to the MVC 4 beta, I get the message "} expected" from files called App_Web_2x0hrczu.0.cs and App_Web_supamddr.3.cs.  They're generated files, obviously, but they appear to refer to a partial view (a .cshtml).  Everything used to work, so I'm confused!  Any ideas?

Comment: Please show us the partial view.

Comment: @MishaTs: That can have nothing to do with a server-side error.

Comment: Problem solved - I just needed to get the app building.  I wanted to have MVC 4 beta side-by-side on my machine, but didn't need this particular app to be MVC 4.  I replaced all the MVC assembly references with MVC 3 references and things began working again . . .

Comment: Can you provide your comment as an answer and accept it please.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13864352/446681